# How does the recursion work in heap-sort?

Tags: recursion, heapsort

Let's say I have an array A = <1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5>
pseudocode for Heapsort:

```
BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)
n = A.heapsize = A.length
for i = floor(n/2) down to 1
   MAX-HEAPIFY(A,i)

MAX-HEAPIFY(A,i)
n = A.heap-size
l = LEFT(i)
r = RIGHT(i)
if l <= n and A[l] > A[i]
   largest = l
if r <= n and A[r] > A[largest]
   largest = r
if largest != i
   exchange A[i] <-> A[largest]
   MAX-HEAPIFY(A,largest)
```

I know BUILD-MAX-HEAP will first call MAX-HEAPIFY(A,4), which will exchange 7 and 9, then after MAX-HEAPIFY (A,3) it will switch 8 and 2. Then it will call MAX-HEAPIFY(A,2), and this is where I get confused. This is how the heap looks when MAX-HEAPIFY(A,2) is called [image]

The first thing that will happen is that 6 and 7 will be exchanged, then it will call MAX-HEAPIFY(A,4) (because 4 is now largest), and exchange 6 and 9, then it will call MAX-HEAPIFY(A,8) but nothing will happen because you've reached a leaf, so then it returns to the function that called it.

MAX-HEAPIFY(A-8) was called by MAX-HEAPIFY(A,4) so it returns to it

MAX-HEAPIFY(A,4) was called by MAX-HEAPIFY(A,2) so it returns to it

but now A[2] < A[4] (because 7 < 9), and it is at this point that I wonder how it knows to call MAX-HEAPIFY(A,2) again to exchange 7 and 9. When a recursive function (or subroutine) returns to the one that called it, there is no more code to be executed (since MAX-HEAPIFY only calls MAX-HEAPIFY at the end of the function), so it will return back up the recursion stack and in my mind it feels like 7 will still be the parent of 9

Sorry if this is confusing, but can somebody walk me through this to help me understand how exactly this is recursively max-heapifying itself?

Comment: Could you explain your pseudo-code better?  For starters: What do the LEFT and RIGHT functions return?  How does this comparison: `if r <= n and A[r] > A[largest]` work if the variable, `largest` doesn't get assigned in the previous step?

Comment: Sorry. LEFT(i) returns 2i, and RIGHT(i) returns 2i +1. largest is originally initialized to i @Gerrat

Comment: Are you using 1-based indexes, or should both your `<=` comparisons actually just be `<` (otherwise you'll be trying to reference non-existent array elements) ?

Comment: yeah I'm doing 1-based indexed. This is just pseudocode from my algorithms class, so I haven't actually implemented it in any language @Gerrat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the series of steps I get when following your algorithm (note the levels of indent when we recurse at the end of each).  Every time we exit the function, we just return to the main program (calling `max_heapify` with the numbers 4 down to 1).  I'm not positive where your interpretation is off, but I'm hoping the following makes it clearer.

```
for i in (4,3,2,1):
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A,i)

MAX-HEAPIFY(A,4):
    largest=4  # initialized
    l=8
    r=9
    largest=8  # calculated
    swap A[4] and a[8]:
    A = <1,6,2,9,3,8,4,7,5>
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 8):
        largest=8  # initialized
        l=16
        r=17
        ...return
    ...return

MAX-HEAPIFY(A,3):
    largest=3  # initialized
    l=6
    r=7
    largest=6  # calculated
    swap A[3] and A[6]:
    A = <1,6,8,9,3,2,4,7,5>
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 6):
        largest=6
        l=12
        r=13
        ...return
    ...return

MAX-HEAPIFY(A,2):
    largest=2 # initialized
    l=4
    r=5
    largest=4 # calculated
    swap A[2]and A[4]:
    A = <1,9,8,6,3,2,4,7,5>
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 4):
        largest=4  # initialized
        l=8
        r=9
        largest=8
        swap A[4] and A[8]:
        A = <1,9,8,7,3,2,4,6,5>
        MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 8):
            largest=8  # initialized
            l=16
            r=17
            ...return
        ...return
     ...return

MAX-HEAPIFY(A,1):
    largest=1  # initialized
    l=2
    r=3
    largest=2  # calculated
    swap A[1] and A[2]:
    A = <9,1,8,7,3,2,4,6,5>
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 2):
        largest=2:  # initialized
        l=4
        r=5
        largest=4:  # calculated
        swap A[2] and A[4]:
        A = <9,7,8,1,3,2,4,6,5>
        MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 4):
            largest=4:  # initialized
            l=8
            r=9
            largest=8:  # calculated
            swap A[4] and A[8]:
            A = <9,7,8,6,3,2,4,1,5>
            MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 8):
                largest=8:  # initialized
                l=16
                r=17        
                ...return
            ...return
        ...return
    ...return

Done!
A = <9,7,8,6,3,2,4,1,5>
```

I then went so far as to translate your algorithm (almost directly) into python (note I had to make a few tweaks for python's 0-based index):

```
def build_max_heap(A):
    for i in range(len(A)//2, 0, -1): 
        max_heapify(A, i)

def left(x):
    return 2 * x

def right(x):
    return 2 * x + 1


def max_heapify(A, i):
    n = len(A)
    largest = i
    l = left(i)
    r = right(i)
    if l<=n and A[l-1] > A[i-1]:
        largest = l
    if r <=n and A[r-1] > A[largest-1]:
        largest = r
    if largest !=i:
        A[i-1], A[largest-1] = A[largest-1], A[i-1]
        max_heapify(A,largest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5]
    build_max_heap(A)  # modifies in-place
    print(A)
```

This prints:
[9, 7, 8, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
(which agrees with our manual iterations)

...and for one more check, using python's `heapq` module with its private method `_heapify_max`:

```
import heapq
A = [1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5]
heapq._heapify_max(A)
print(A)
```

...prints the same:
[9, 7, 8, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5]

Comment: Hmm. Okay I feel like an idiot now. My confusion stemmed from the fact that when I was drawing out the heap after each MAX-HEAPIFY, I didn't switch the 7 and the 9 when I should have when it called MAX-HEAPIFY(A,4), so 7 and 9 weren't in the positions they should have been by the time I got to HEAPIFY(A,2). If we start with MAX-HEAPIFY(A,4), by the time we get to MAX-HEAPIFY(A,2), the tree rooted at index 4 will already be a max heap--so my question was kinda stupid now that I look at it. @Gerrat

Comment: I was stumped on the same thing. I would explain it like this: Once you move an element down the heap you may have to keep on moving it down. This is because the heap below it is maxed, but you may have just placed something lower than its max there. 
These algorithms are a little hard to read because you heapify "Largest". The GOTCHA is that "Largest" is no longer the largest because of the swap, now it's the low one that just got kicked down.